# the count value in powershell is not correct when the path has special character. $path =(get-childitem "c:\test`[N`]").count

Tags: powershell-4.0

if the path is like c:\test[N] why the count does not work? I mean $path =(get-childitem "c:\test`[N`]").count does not give the count value

Answer (score 0):

Use **-LiteralPath** instead of the (position 0) **-Path**:

```
(get-childitem -LiteralPath "c:\test[N]").Count
```